# Single word for "positive impact"

Tags: vocabulary

What single word can I use to denote `positive contribution` or `positive impact`? E.g.:

```
He was let go because his burden outweighed his [positive impact]
```

I thought of using `benefit` but that word doesn't really clarify to whom it is directed (to the let go employee or the company, in the above example)

Comment: I think there's something not quite right about ***his** burden* there (it's probably not *him* who's carrying or "owning" a burden - his ***drawbacks*** are a burden to the company who're *firing* him). Common juxtapositions include *advantages/disadvantages* and *benefits/drawbacks*.

Comment: Not sure you can say: his burden here. He was a burden, he didn't have a burden. Your choice of answer will leave you with a weird sentence. His burdensomeness is very heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He was let go because his burden outweighed his contributions.

I think this is the phrase you are looking for. "Contribution" has a default positive connotation.

Comment: Actually, the sentence doesn't make much sense. Because he was a burden.

Answer (score 4):

He was let go because his burden outweighed his *usefulness*.